# Delete ASP.NET Temp files using windows services

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, vba

We are trying to create windows services, which’ll run every day at 3 AM in morning. The service basically, removes/delete ASP.NET Temp files. 
We were able to find the command line argument to stop/start IIS and delete Temp files. Also, we created a simple windows services.
However, we have couple of issues:

1. Temporary Folder permission is reset to Read only and we need to manually change it to remove read only permission.
2. Based on google search we had, we aren’t sure: how to call DOS command from windows services at regular interval. Do we need to use batch file to execute DOS command and if so, then how to do that.

Below is command to stop/start iis and delete temporary files.

iisreset /stop
C:\WINDOWS\system32>del /S/Q "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temp
orary ASP.NET Files\"

iisreset /start

Can anyone guide us? Do we need to use window services or task scheduler to stop iis, remove folder permission and delete temp folder. Sample example/instruction will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A windows service is a bit overkill for this. All you really need is a scheduled task to kick off to run your commands and set it to run under the instance of a user that has access to the local IIS_IUSRS group (or any with elevated permissions to that folder.)

For example with powershell:

invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset /stop}

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" -Include *.* -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}

invoke-command -scriptblock {iisreset /start}

The setup a scheduled task like so:
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

And set it to run as a user that has elevated permissions to that folder.

You would most likely want to also add a powershell web request to your sites once IIS comes back up or else the first person to hit the site again after you do this is in for an extended initial load time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will consider your suggestion and look into it in details. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Powershell script, without stopping IIS:

```
foreach($childItem in Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root')
{
    $folderNameToDelete = $childItem.FullName + "_delete"
    Rename-Item $childItem.FullName $folderNameToDelete -ErrorVariable errs -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($errs.Count -eq 0)
    {
        Remove-Item $folderNameToDelete -Recurse
    }
}
```